# The 'abc' property on 'xyz' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, nullable

I'm trying to get a function import to work correctly. EF calls out to my stored procedure, but the result has an inner exception that I don't understand:

> The 'IsPublished' property on 'uspLoadTemplateByID_Result' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a
>   non-null value of type 'Boolean'.

My designer.cs are

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Boolean> IsPublished
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsPublished;
            }
            set
            {
                OnIsPublishedChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("IsPublished");
                _IsPublished = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("IsPublished");
                OnIsPublishedChanged();
            }
        }
        private Nullable<global::System.Boolean> _IsPublished;
        partial void OnIsPublishedChanging(Nullable<global::System.Boolean> value);
        partial void OnIsPublishedChanged();
```

Comment: Er... That message seems self-explanatory to me. If Entity Framework is working on the assumption that your stored procedure has a bit column in its results (because that's what you specified, explicitly or implicitly), but your stored procedure actually has an int column in its place, what behaviour would you expect?

Comment: Yea you are right but the in this case store procedure return the boolean type value and in all edmx.designer.cs I could not find any Int32 type for ispublished attribute., In Designer of entity framwork field show boolean but in inner exception it take nullable issue.

Comment: could you show your class, mapping and stored procedure?

Comment: StoreProcedure return this record:    "SELECT  ID, TemplateName, [Description], Code, [Version], SaveCount,ModuleType,'Module' As ReportType, ApplicationID, ISNULL(IsPublished,0) AS IsPublished"